# PyTelegramBotApi - how to stop one function if other function is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to do an optional input, and have this code

```
 bot.send_chat_action(message.from_user.id, 'typing')
 markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
 markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Лечу только в одну сторону", callback_data="one_way"))
 msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '✅Хорошо. Теперь введите дату возвращения:', reply_markup=markup)
 bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_return_date)
```

This code sends user a message with button to skip this step, and registers function get_return_date(), that waits for a date value. [Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyoe0.png)
And if user clicks the button, query handler register another function get_adults(), that waits for numeric value:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "one_way")
def is_one_way(call):
    msg = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,
                           '✅Хорошо. Сколько взрослых (пассажиров старше 12-ти лет на момент полёта) полетят ‍?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_adults)
    return
```

And, trouble is that - if user clicks the button to skip, both get_return_date() and get_adults() are waiting for a value and work at one time:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaAgD.png)

Any ideas what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
bot.send_chat_action(message.from_user.id, 'typing')
 msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '✅Хорошо. Теперь введите дату возвращения: (you can skip this passage with /skip)')
 bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_return_date)

def get_retourn_date(message):
    if message.text == '/skip':
        get_adults()
        return
    # write here the actual function code
```

Answer (score 1):

i use query callbacks and i put this func at the begining of the callback:

```
bot.clear_step_handler_by_chat_id(call.message.chat.id)
```

u can use it like this

```
def gen_markup():
  markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
  markup.row_width = 1
  markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Button 1", callback_data="one"),
             InlineKeyboardButton("Button 2", callback_data="two"))


def ButtonOneFunc(message):
   #do whatever u want here

def ButtonTwoFunc(message):
   #do whatever u want here


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call):
  bot.clear_step_handler_by_chat_id(call.message.chat.id)
  if call.data == "one":
    sent= bot.reply_to(call.message, "This is Button 1")  
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, ButtonOneFunc) 
  elif call.data == "two":
    sent= bot.reply_to(call.message, "This is Button 2")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, ButtonTwoFunc)
```

what will happen here is, whenever the user will click a button, it will clear all next_register_handler that were open
and then enter the new call.data and set the handler which the user clicked on